# Cron jobs not running in VestaCP (CentOs)

Tags: cron, centos, vesta

I have written some PHP scripts that I am trying to run with cron jobs in VestaCP, but they don't seem to be running. I have tried to search for other threads on here and on the VestaCP forum that could help me identify the error, but have not found a solution.

Server system:

- CentOs 7.4
- Vesta 0.9.8-22

I have tested the PHP scripts by going to the links directly. They all work well. But the cron jobs are not running and I can't figure out why.

I have not been able to locate any error messages or logs generated by these cron jobs (even when I remove the "> /dev/null 2>&1"). But I might have been looking in the wrong places.

All of the cron jobs have been added through the VestaCP cron interface.

I have disabled exim, dovecot, clamd, and spamassassin. And I have turned off notifications in the cron panel. Not sure if that is related.

Copied from /var/spool/cron/admin [edited domain name]:

```
15 02 * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue disk

10 00 * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue traffic

30 03 * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue webstats

*/5 * * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue backup

10 05 * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-backup-users

20 00 * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-user-stats

*/5 * * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-rrd

15 6 * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-vesta-all

01 4 * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-letsencrypt-ssl

*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - "https://testing.example.com/cli/new-projects" > /dev/null 2>&1

*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - "https://example.com/cli/new-projects" > /dev/null 2>&1

30 10 * * * wget -q -O - "https://example.com/cli/project-expiration" > /dev/null 2>&1

*/5 * * * * sudo /usr/local/vesta/bin/v-update-sys-queue letsencrypt

0 10 * * * wget -q -O - "https://testing.example.com/cli/project-expiration" > /dev/null 2>&1

*/2 * * * * wget -q -O - "https://testing.example.com/cli/email-sender" > /dev/null 2>&1

*/2 * * * * wget -q -O - "https://example.com/cli/email-sender" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu.

The problem was that the cron jobs created from VestaCP control panel is created for the user and although there is sudo at the beginning of the command, they are not run.

They seem to be called since I can see them on the /tmp/log/syslog file. It does not show any error though. But for some reason, the commands are not executed.

Here are few simple commands to check cron status.

Check if Cron service is running:

```
pgrep cron
```

if a number is returned the service is running else not
Check Cron status:

```
systemctl status cron
```

Check the current cron file:

```
crontab -l
```

Edit cronjob file:

```
crontab -e
```

One solution is to create the cron jobs for the root user from the terminal. I have not tried for other users. The cron jobs created for root user will run without a problem.